# String encryption in a .NET assembly

Tags: .net, security, obfuscation

Are there any free tools similar to [Dotfuscator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotfuscator)? I want to encrypt or obfuscate certain strings inside my .NET assembly.

Answer (score 2):

I would think obfuscators only change the symbolnames, but not string literals.

So for extra String protection you'd need to garble/ungarble (encrypt/decrypt) the text yourself

But look out. If the strings are really sensitive, the best encryption won't do you good, since if the decryption method/keys are in the same program as well (since the program needs the decrypted version of the text) than your strings are still able to be decrypted.